# Recommendations on a rigid connection between materials

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, welding, joining

I am trying to construct a torsion pendulum/balance for a physics experiment but the research papers are always missing specifics on how the certain connections are made.

I am looking for recommendations on rigid connections for:

1. How to attach a glass mirror to tungsten wire.
2. How to attach tungsten wire to torsion pendulum/balance beam.
3. How to attach PLA to glass.
4. How to attach glass to glass (I do not have the capability to melt them).

[Here is a link](http://www.leydenscience.org/physics/gravitation/cavend.htm) to an example experimental setup. The balance beam I am using is actually quartz glass tube. The wire is tungsten. The plastic components are 3d printed and are PLA. The total weight is about 22lbs suspended from the tungsten wire.

(I posted this in the Physics exchange and they closed it claiming it is an engineering problem)

Comment: Material interfaces could be mechanical or by adhesion. Given the number of possible materials involved and the fabrication technologies needed, it would be helpful to narrow the options if you are looking for meaningful answers.  Perhaps you could add a diagram to help define scale and proportion and the loadings involved.

Comment: You do have ability to attach glass to glass. It's easier than you think. A household gas stove is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping things simple...

1. epoxy
2. design a fitting suitable for 3D printing to mechanically attach the parts
3. if the part needs to detach, design a fitting, otherwise epoxy
4. epoxy

Comment: Any recommendation on a metal free epoxy you have had good results with?

Comment: Any methylmethacrylate adhesive will also do the job   -  Plastic Welder-II from Devcon for example.